# Jetty - HashLoginService.putUser deprecated?

Tags: deprecated, embedded-jetty

Given this method:

```
private static SecurityHandler basicAuth(String username, String password) {
    HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService();
    loginService.putUser(username, Credential.getCredential(password), new String[]{"user"});

    Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
    constraint.setName(Constraint.__DIGEST_AUTH);
    constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user"});
    constraint.setAuthenticate(true);

    ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
    constraintMapping.setConstraint(constraint);
    constraintMapping.setPathSpec("/*");

    ConstraintSecurityHandler csh = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
    csh.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
    csh.addConstraintMapping(constraintMapping);
    csh.setLoginService(loginService);
    return csh;
}
```

It does not compile for current versions of jetty, the "putUser" method is deprecated from the HashLoginService class.

Where or how can I find out what has superceded Jetty's HashLoginService.putUser method's functionality so the above code will compile against more current Jetty versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this can be solved with reference to this question's answer:

[HashLoginService and Jetty9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263651/hashloginservice-and-jetty9)

E. g. instead of using

```
loginService.putUser(...);
```

to create the required list of users, instantiate an instance of the UserStore class

```
UserStore userStore = new UserStore();
```

and then instead of calling putUser(...) to add users, add them to the store first e. g.

```
userStore.addUser(a.getLogonName().toUpperCase().trim(), new Password(password), new String[]{"user"});
```

and then later reference the "userStore" object in the loginService e.g.

```
loginService.setUserStore(userStore);
```

My final code which seems to work for effectively replacing putUser:

```
private SecurityHandler getSecuritySetup() {
        final HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService();

        UserStore userStore = new UserStore();
        
        try {                              
                for (Agent a : Agent.FetchAllAgents()) {
                    if ((a.getAgentTypeNo().compareTo("4") <= 0) || (a.getLogonName().startsWith("DZX")) || (a.getLogonName().startsWith("GZX")) || (a.getLogonName().startsWith("HZX")) || (a.getLogonName().startsWith("FZX"))) {

                        userStore.addUser(a.getLogonName().toUpperCase().trim(), new Password(password), new String[]{"user"});
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (Agent a : Agent.FetchAllAgents()) {
                    if (a.getAgentTypeNo().compareTo("443") <= 0) {

                        userStore.addUser(a.getLogonName().toLowerCase().trim(), new Password(password), new String[]{"user"});
                        userStore.addUser(a.getLogonName().toUpperCase().trim(), new Password(password), new String[]{"user"});
                    }
                }
            }

            loginService.setName("admin");
        } catch (SQLException sex) {
            localLogger.error((String) logEntryRefNumLocal.get() + "SQL exception in getBasicAuthHandler in WebHost.java.", sex);
        } catch (RuntimeException rex) {
            localLogger.error((String) logEntryRefNumLocal.get() + "Runtime exception in getBasicAuthHandler in WebHost.java.", rex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            localLogger.error((String) logEntryRefNumLocal.get() + "General exception in getBasicAuthHandler in WebHost.java.", ex);
        }

        loginService.setUserStore(userStore);
        
        final Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
        constraint.setName(Constraint.__BASIC_AUTH);
        constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user"});
        constraint.setAuthenticate(true);

        final ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = new ConstraintMapping();
        constraintMapping.setConstraint(constraint);
        constraintMapping.setPathSpec("/secure_path/*");

        final ConstraintSecurityHandler csh = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
        csh.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
        csh.setRealmName("theRoot");
        csh.addConstraintMapping(constraintMapping);
        csh.setLoginService(loginService);

        return csh;
    }
```

Now, I need to provide a username and password when accessing any .jsp pages in the /secure/ subfolder of my embedded Jetty's .jar.